# Why would you subtract the mean of your variance from your variance?

Tags: variance, normalization, standardization

i recently stumbled over the following codeline:

```
variancedm<-variance-mean(variance)
```

Is this a common way to normalize/standardize variance ? 
Why would you do this before running a regression ?